# Integration Services Import different sections of same Excel sheet

Tags: excel, join, ssis, merge

I have a set of 40+ sheets in an .xlsx file.  Each is an organization with a main contact and their info in a vertical structure.  There are no headers for this section.

`Organization:       |Fillory            |
Main Contact Name:  |Aiden Turner       |Lead Instructor
Main Contact Email: |Ludo@rocks.com 
Main Contact Phone: |508-555-2112
Mailing Address:    |123 Baker Street   |Brockton, MA 02301`

Other associated people are in a sheet, but without address info.
`First Name |Last Name  |Individual Email Address`

I want to connect to the Excel file and get the top 5 rows and 3 columns to pivot the first column against the other two,  then cross apply them with the records below starting with the header at row 7.

I started down the path of a MergeJoin, but that got me into a whole IsSorted thing and before I start trying to troubleshoot whatever I'm doing wrong, I figured I should see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: You can select a range of columns in Excel Source Editor choose Data acces mode -> SQL Command and write in SQL command text (eg):
SELECT * FROM [SheetName 1$A3:K]